# How to initialize string in Class in c++ (g++ )

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error while initializing a string in a class

**Error :**
    publicclass.cpp:13:6: error: array type 'char [50]' is not assignable
    s.n = "Randomstring";

**But char is working. Only getting error with strings**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
  public:
  int ht;
  char n[50];
};

int main()
{
  student s;
  s.ht = 1;
  s.n = "Randomstring";
  cout<<"Hallticket no : "<<s.ht<<"\n";
  cout<<"Name : "<<s.n<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

**Compiler version is g++ 8.0.0 (getting same error with clang++ ,turboc++(in windows))**

Comment: Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: If you do need to use a char[] and not a std::string then you will need to [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) a value into it (or strncpy if there's any risk the source string is larger than the target buffer, or snprintf, etc.). You can't just use equals.

Comment: [Link for your c++ teacher](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are not assignable.

You can initialise the member when you initialise the object that contains it:

```
student s{1, "Randomstring"};
```

You can copy the elements of an existing array after initialisation:

```
std::strncpy(s.n, "Randomstring", std::size(s.n));
```